# Windows no reconoce el comando conda

Tags: python, django, anaconda, conda

Estoy intentando usar Anaconda, pero cuando ejecuto el comando:

```
conda activate base
```

Recibo un error diciendo que el término "conda" no se reconoce como nombre de un archivo de script o programa ejecutable:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué puedo hacer para que me funcione el comando `conda`?

Comment: Es porque debes instalarlo. https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/windows.html

Comment: El mismo error describe que no lo tienes instalado correctamente o no esta instalado,por favor revisa [ask] para formular preguntas en el sitio,saludos.

Comment: Si lo tienes instalado, es posible que no esté registrada su carpeta en la variable de entorno Path. Puedes añadirlo tanto como variable del sistema como de usuario. Lo haces yendo a Propiedades del sistema -> Opciones avanzadas -> Variables de entorno y allí se enuentra Path para que lo puedas editar.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías de verificar si ya instalaste anaconda correctamente.

Si no la opcion mas viable seria reinstalarlo sin marcar la casilla de crear los caminos crea una carpeta para reinstalar.

C:\Anaconda\Python

Podría ser la mejor opción y posteriormente

C:AnacondaPython

C:AnacondaPythonScripts

C:AnacondaPythonLibrary

C:AnacondaPythonLibrarymingw-w64bin

C:AnacondaPythonLibraryusrbin